# i want to change my URL Through htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to change my url through .htaccess here is all code i am trying.
i write 2 codes for same page, in second page i am adding mode varible but it is showing me like this :

```
free/english-lession/learn-about-influential-people&mode=advanced 

Options -Indexes
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +MultiViews
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /page\?type=(.*)&lang=(.*)&id=(.*)\ HTTP
    RewriteRule ^ /page/%2/%3/%4\? [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /page\?type=(.*)&lang=(.*)&id=(.*)&mode=(.*)\ HTTP
    RewriteRule ^ /page/%2/%3/%4/%5\? [R,L]


    </IfModule>
```

Comment: can you please paste here what actually you want as in url ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: What does "i am not getting variable data" mean?

Comment: i am getting this url in second one .. first one is working. if i am adding mode to same url then it stop working   free/english-lession/learn-about-influential-people&mode=advanced